# How to move files among folder in the same s3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I'm trying to move a file into another folder in the same bucket, my code didn't return any errors, but the folder has not been moved.
There is a space of the name of one folder.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'bucket',
    'Key': 'config/L C/aa/bb/cc/Lab/xx.tgz'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'bucket', 'config/L C/aa/bb/cc/Pilot/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it worked for me. I didn't find the direct way to move files, but copy and paste first and then delete.

```
#copy first
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'bucket',
    'Key': 'xx/aa/m.tgz'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'bucket', 'xx/bb/m.tgz')

#delete the orginal, but assert if the one has been moved
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucketname='pp'
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketname)
key = 'xx/tt/m.tgz'
objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key))
if len(objs) > 0 and objs[0].key == key:
    print("exist")
    # here we delete the previous file
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    s3s = session.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    obj = s3s.Object(bucketname, "xx/bb/m.tgz")
    obj.delete()
```

Comment: Great! Some tips: You do not need to keep calling `boto3.resource()`. You can just keep using `s3` that is defined at the top. Also, you do not need to put the Access Key and Secret Key in your code. Instead, use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command to store the credentials in a configuration file. You can then just use `s3=boto3.resource('s3')`.